# Как сочетать интерфейс на C# с кодом на Python?

Tags: python, c#, .net, winforms

Готовим проект для универа. Задумка заключается в том, что пишем интерфейс на C# и алгоритм шифровщика на пайтоне но незнаем как вшить Python в интерфейс.
Чтобы каждая кнопка выполняла свою функцию и т.д.

Comment: _алгоритм шифровщика на пайтоне_ - на C# быстрее же будет работать...хотя как уметь писать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этих целей вы можете использовать [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/):

```
dotnet add package IronPython
```

либо через менеджер пакетов в Visual Studio/Rider

Пример кода:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

int y = 22;

ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("y", y);
engine.ExecuteFile("hello.py", scope);
dynamic x = scope.GetVariable("x");
dynamic z = scope.GetVariable("z");
Console.WriteLine($"{x} + {y} = {z}");
```